# About the WebRTC offer and answer problem

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have 2 devices named A and B
I found that if the Caller(i.e. device A) does not have Webcam, the callee side(i.e. device B)  generated answer does not have any video information even the callee side have a webcam.

In the end, the device A can not show the remote video stream.

However, when I swapping the role of these devices, the callee (i.e. device A) generated answer has video information even device A does not have a webcam , Why?

Is it any philosophy behind?
Is there any other way to ensure the callee side can show the remote video stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute by passing option to the createOffer() method.

```
pc.createOffer({
  offerToReceiveAudio: true,
  offerToReceiveVideo: true
});
```